# Как дублировать значение (строку) в бд Access при помощи python?

Tags: python, ms-access, копирование

Прошу помощи. Хочу создать копию строки в базе данных Access с помощью python. Но в строке имеется некие двоичные данные, которые не получается скопировать обычными методами, которые я знаю (хотя python и считывает и печатает содержимое если просишь). Возможно ли вообще осуществить, то что я хочу, если да то как?
Код моих манипуляций ниже.

```
import pyodbc

MDB = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\db1.mdb"
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}".format(DRV, MDB, ''))
cur = con.cursor()

sql_ins = f"SELECT data FROM table1 WHERE OBJ='123'"
cur.execute(sql_ins)
data_new = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(data_new)
try:
    sql_ins = f"INSERT INTO table1  (OBJ, data) VALUES ('124', '{data_new}')"
    cur.execute(sql_ins)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
except Exception as ex:
    print("ошибка", ex)
    con.close()
```

Вывод:

```
F:\Python\read_bd\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:/Python/read_bd/main.py
b'?\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
ошибка ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect  (17) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

База данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17MO1NYVx9bjZcYPcTkQCIJb1gz-Qp0k-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: А где структура таблицы table1 с типами данных

Comment: Все мои действия с таблицами ms access ограничиваются вышеприведенными действиями (считать, записать).  Я в теме прикрепил ссылку с базой. Иной информации у меня к сожалению нет.

Comment: Используйте параметризованный запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyodbc

MDB = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\db1.mdb"
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}".format(DRV, MDB, ''))
cur = con.cursor()

sql_ins = f"SELECT data FROM table1 WHERE OBJ='123'"
cur.execute(sql_ins)
data_new = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(data_new)
try:
    sql_ins = f"INSERT INTO table1  (OBJ, data) VALUES ('124', ?)"
    cur.execute(sql_ins,(data_new,))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
except Exception as ex:
    print("ошибка", ex)
    con.close()


con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}".format(DRV, MDB, ''))
cur = con.cursor()
res=cur.execute('select * from table1').fetchall()
print(res)
con.close()
```

---

```
b'?\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
[('123', b'?\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'), ('124', b'?\x00\x00\x00\xc1\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')]
```

В запросе ожидалось LONGBINARY, а вставлялась строка. Лучше даже исправить так :

```
sql_ins = f"INSERT INTO table1  (OBJ, data) VALUES (?, ?)" 
cur.execute(sql_ins,('124',data_new))
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно! До этого не использовал параметры в запросах и как оказалось зря